# How to integrate blockchain contracts mentioned in ABI file to android app?

Tags: android, blockchain, solidity

I've been trying to support android app to invoke block chain contract methods. I've ABI file that lists all the contracts to be invoked and tried to convert it using [sol2proto](https://github.com/getamis/sol2proto) and also tried to generate java wrapper files using [web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) command line. What should be an appropriate way to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include web3j in Android code. Configure web3 with infura and then instantiate smart contract's instance using its and ABI and then you would be good to invoke smart contract

Comment: On Infura, would I be able to link contracts other than the ethereum? I read on Infura and it is all related to ethereum

Comment: Yes, infura only develops for Ethereum at the moment.

Comment: Okay, so we've a private blockchain and I want the contract to invoke on that blockchain. Do you know how to do it?